# How do I make a div extend its width beyond the parent's width?

Tags: html, css

I have a `wrapper` div and a `content` div.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #content {
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .column {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="column">hello</div>
        <div class="column">world</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `column`s appear on two rows instead of the same row. If I style then with `display: table-cell` they each take up 50% of the width, but still won't expand the `content` beyond the `wrapper`'s width.

How do I make the `content` div expand to fit both `column`s on the same row and cause scrolling on the `wrapper` div?

Comment: try adding `white-space:nowrap; display: inline-block;` to `#content`: http://jsfiddle.net/PC5nn/

Comment: @Pete Please put that as an answer.

Comment: answer added - I have added a few extra styles in  (and updated fiddle)to get the content of the columns to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change you styles to the following you will achieve what you want:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.column {
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PC5nn/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Ohh I think I see the problem now, try:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    white-space:nowrap;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krowe/z3TS8/

Comment: The number of columns changes dynamically as well as the widths of the columns. The stylesheet should accommodate any kind of content.

Answer (score 0):

In .column if you use display:table-cell, the column will be aligned in the same row as you need. And its working fine for me. Hope this is what you are looking for [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/z3TS8/5/)

```
 #wrapper {
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      overflow: auto;
      display:table;
  }
  #content {
      overflow: hidden;
      display:table-row;
  }
  .column {
      width:50%;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      display:table-cell;
  }
```